# Baleful polymorph on a dragon and spells with a somatic component

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A dragon can cast spells with a somatic elements. If the dragon is polymorphed with [*baleful polymorph*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/balefulPolymorph.html) into a mouse and passes the second saving throw retaining the ability to cast spells:

- will he still be able to cast spells with the somatic component?
- will he still be able to cast spells with the verbal component?

A mouse cannot speak and is not really similar to a dragon so I would tend to assume that both answers are a **no** but then I would not see why the ability to cast spells is retained since it would be rarely the case that someone balefully polymorphs a creature in a similar creature able to speak ...

Comment: Probably no, but as a GM i'd say yes (for lulz).

Comment: It will always, of course, be the DM's call. We used to have a Warmage that was polymorphed into a hummingbird and the DM allowed him to retain his spellcasting abilities; he found the change to be... favorable.

Comment: @Cthoc: OK, thus: In settings, where (some types of) dragons have the shapechanger subtype, they "can revert to its natural form as a standard action" [Baleful Polymorph](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/balefulPolymorph.html). This does not apply to Pathfinder, because just "several of the Metallic Dragons get Change shape as a *supernatural ability and special quality*" (Cthos) only, not as subtype. (Thanks to Cthos for pointing this out!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.  Probably.**

Specifically, a dragon Baleful Polymorph'd into a mouse can no longer speak, and probably can't make precise hand motions.  The definition of Verbal components says:

> To provide a verbal component, you must be able to speak in a strong voice.

Likewise with Somatic:

> A somatic component is a measured and precise movement of the hand.

You could absolutely make the argument that a mouse can still make precise hand motions, but I feel like that comes down to exactly how precise the GM wants it to be; it could either mean precise finger motions as well, or just moving your hand around.

Basically, as long as the spell doesn't have verbal or somatic components (like a Silent Still spell), the dragon can cast it.  Otherwise, he cannot.

The specifics on spell components are [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components).

Comment: That does not necessarily rule out spells that don't need any of those components like, say, Glorious Master of the Elements. It can also use a Silent spell with no somatic component, a Still spell with no verbal component... you get the idea. It would also be able to use its spell-like abilities (["A spell-like ability has no verbal, somatic, or material component, nor does it require a focus or have an XP cost."](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellLikeAbilities)).

Comment: Dragons don't have hands to begin with -- that should at least be acknowledged in the answer!

Comment: @starwed Oddly enough, in second edition AD&D, dragons explicitly did cast spells without somatic components, but that bit of info didn't get carried into Third and later editions, so GMs were forced to invent their own explanations.